# Server-side paging with filtering and sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

In our web application we have some data-intensive UI pages that are quite slow, and the client-side sorting and filtering we're using now is forcing these pages to load all the data from the API (in JSON) and then perform the operations in the browser which usually means the page freezes for several seconds before it's ready for use.
The solution we're looking into is to provide server-side paging with support for filtering and sorting.

For paging, we are sending the pageIndex and pageSize parameters in the URL and it works fine. Now for sorting (and filtering) we are thinking of sending the names of the properties to sort (and filter) with inside a JSON object that can be parsed by the API to generate a proper query for the data. The problem I have here is that to make things as simple and fast as possible, the UI pages will have to “know” about the data column names according which they want to sort (or filter) data, which is not desirable.

For example, the API sends users first names in a property called “FN” (in a JSON object); however, to ask the API to sort users according by first names, the UI will have to send “FirstName” as the sorting property which is the name of the column in my database. This method allows me to pass the name of the property directly to my data layer and get things done quickly. However, the need of the UI to recognize the names of the columns of the data tables in the database pretty much undoes the whole idea of separating concerns between layers (which was a major motivation for us to break down our web app into separate API and UI).

Is there a clean way to provide the server-side paging with filtering and sorting without creating this dependency between the UI and the backend?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this a problem of your own making? - why does the UI "have" to send "FirstName" rather than using the same identifiers (e.g. `FN`) that your API already sends to it?

Comment: Passing "FirstName" like I said was the simplest thing to do. I could send "FN", but then I have to add something to translate this to "FirstName" to generate a suitable query. I am aware of this solution but I am trying to find out if there are better practices or tools out there to make this work.

Comment: The overheads of translating the names is likely to be swamped, many times over, by the overheads you incur in actually accessing the data and *performing* the sorting and filtering.

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I am going to wait for a few more answers but I think this is the most reasonable way to go about it. Can you please make your comments into an answer so that I am able to flag as a solution if I end up using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see much problem here. Don't know how *exactly* your app structured, but let's assume we have a table with 2 columns (Acol, Bcol). What is the *name* of the column is written in attributes (Acol: "First name", "LastName" or in Italian "Nome", "Cognome", who cares..) of the column itself, so in the moment user in some way requests to sort or to filter, you don't pass the fixed name of the column, but the string present in attributes of that column. And who sets the attribute on the column? the server.

So server sets alias for the columns (real names, may be translated to fit localize context of the client), and the client what does is simply passing that string, without even understanding what it for to a server, because the server knows what to do.

Comment: Thank you @tigran. This is one of many possibilities to create a "mapper" between the "language" the UI is using the actual internal "hardcoded" names. I am not sure I like the idea of creating this mapping at such a low level as the database column name. While this might work much faster, it leaves less room for maneuverability. For example, a mapper created at a higher level in the application structure would allow me to create different mappings for different clients of the API. This is not required at the moment, but I usually prefer to leave myself some elbow room.

Comment: @WassimMansour: no this is not abot mapping. **Server** injects column "real" (the name is used to query a data) and translated name, or alias. One time clicked, UI simply passed to the server real name, hence UI does not do any maping, just get the value present in some known field and say: "server, sort on the field " + filedName found. So the only thing UI must know, is where the real name of the colun is, but what is that, how it's managed, absolutely irrelevent from the point of view of UI. So you maintain UI-BL decoupling.